# GCP Workflow: Handling http functions responses other than 200

Tags: google-workflows

When calling http endpoint in GCP workflow, only HttpStatus 200 is considered a success.

How to handle other Success Status codes? 201, 202, etc.

Example workflow from samples:

```
- readItem:
    try:
      call: http.get
      args:
        url: https://example.com/someapi
        auth:
          type: OIDC
      result: APIResponse
    except:
      as: e
      steps:
        - knownErrors:
            switch:
              - condition: ${not("HttpError" in e.tags)}
                next: connectionProblem
              - condition: ${e.code == 404}
                next: urlNotFound
              - condition: ${e.code == 403}
                next: authProblem
        - UnhandledException:
            raise: ${e}
- urlFound:
    return: ${APIResponse.body}
- connectionProblem:
    return: "Connection problem; check URL"
- urlNotFound:
    return: "Sorry, URL wasn't found"
- authProblem:
    return: "Authentication error"
```

If the api endpoint  https://example.com/someapi returns anything other than a 200 status code the connectionProblem is invoked.

This is the same if its a GET or POST request.

What is the best way of handling this?

Comment: are you sure that urlFound step is not executed? There is no reason why that would not execute. Workflows handles anything avoe 400 as errors https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing referencing how to handle other 200s statuses in the documentation for Google Workflows so I assume this is not possible without treating them as errors.

This means that in order to do it you are going to need to add an extra step to deal with this status as an error handling strategy, like `- condition: ${e.code == 201}` for example.

Alternatively you could open a [feature request in Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=976157&template=1520035) so that they can consider implementing different treatements of such status codes or at least so that this is touched on more details in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At present response codes >= 400 and <= 599 are considered an error and will raise an exception. i.e. 200s are considered a success and will not.

Alternatively, if you want to trigger an exception handler for return codes in this range (or for any other reason), this can be done by adding an additional step to the try call, for example (illustration only):

```
main:
  steps:
    - getStuff:
        try:
            steps:
              - callStep:
                  call: http.get
                  args:
                    url: <SOME URL>
                  result: r
              - checkNotOK:
                  switch:
                    - condition: ${r.code == 202}
                      raise: ${r}
        retry:
          predicate: ${custom_predicate}
          max_retries: 5
          backoff:
            initial_delay: 2
            max_delay: 60
            multiplier: 2

custom_predicate:
  params: [e]
  steps:
    - what_to_repeat:
        switch:
          - condition: ${e.code == 202}
            return: true
    - otherwise:
        return: false
```

Comment: If you want to trigger an exception handler for return codes in this range (or for any other reason), this can be done by adding an additional step to the try call